# Get Date Object of 90 Days in the Future Without Using Library Angular 12

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to get a date 90 days in the future without using an external library in my Angular 12 project. I currently have this line of code that works

```
futureDate = futureDate ?? new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()+90)).toISOString();
```

but I'm looking for a cleaner way to implement this functionality. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var nientyDaysAfter = new Date(Date.now() + (8.64e+7 * 90)).toISOString()

console.log("::90 days later:", nientyDaysAfter)
```

##### a reusable function

```js
var addNDays = function(days) {
  var date = new Date(Date.now());
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
  return date;
}
```